# Tax are not showing on order while placing order with REST API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I'm trying to placing order with REST API which will use for android app. I've used  `wc_create_order()` for placing order but I didn't getting tax values as I got in web view.

What I want - I need to display tax also beside products as I have shared screenshots.

**Order page while order with api.**
[image]

**Order page while order with website(woocommerce checkout page**).
[image]

Here is code what I have used:

```
function wc_place_orders($request){

global $woocommerce;

$order_data = array(
    'status' => apply_filters('woocommerce_default_order_status', 'processing'),
    'customer_id' => $request['user_id'],
    'created_via' => "Created From Andriod App",
);

$address = array(
    'first_name' => $request['first_name'],
    'last_name'  => $request['last_name'],
    'company'    => '',
    'email'      => $request['email'],
    'phone'      => $request['phone'],
    'address_1'  => $request['address_1'],
    'address_2'  => $request['address_2'],
    'city'       => $request['city'],
    'state'      => $request['state'],
    'postcode'   => $request['postcode'],
    'country'    => $request['country'],
);

$order = wc_create_order($order_data);
$order_id = $order->get_id();

$saved_cart_meta = get_user_meta( $request['user_id'], '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_' . get_current_blog_id(), true );

foreach ($saved_cart_meta['cart'] as $key => $value) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $value['product_id'] );
    $order->add_product( $product, $value['quantity']);
}
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_created_via($order_data['created_via']);

// Set payment gateway
$payment_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
$order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateways[$request['payment']] );

//Shipping Fees
$shipping_taxes = WC_Tax::calc_shipping_tax($request['shipping_value'], WC_Tax::get_shipping_tax_rates());
$order->add_shipping(new WC_Shipping_Rate('flat_rate_shipping', $request['shipping_method_title'], $request['shipping_value'], $shipping_taxes, 'flat_rate'));


//Pickup&dropoff time
add_post_meta($order_id, "pickup_date", $request['pickup_date']);
add_post_meta($order_id, "drop_date", $request['drop_date']);


$order->set_total($request['discount'], 'cart_discount');
$order->save();

$order->calculate_taxes();
$order->calculate_totals();

$order->update_status("Completed", 'Created With Android App', TRUE);

return new WP_REST_Response($order, 123);}
```

Comment: WooCommerce already has an API for creating orders? Why not just use that?

Comment: Problem is same with Woocommerce API as well can't extend it well.

Answer (score 2):

This post is old, but I had the same problem with creating an order programmatically. The tax was not calculated ...

We had configured the customer billing address as the default tax base and the country value was "Germany" and it should be "DE" .... We have changed it to the ISO code and now it works fine.